# Change of variable in non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE I wish to study:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2+s}\left(-s (s+1) p(x) p''(x)+(s+1) p''(x)+s (s+1) p'(x)^2-s (s+1) p(x)^2+s p(x)\right)=0
\end{equation}
Where $s\in \mathbb{R}$. When $s=0$ we recover the time independent diffusion equation.

Does this equation have a name? I tried to induce a change of variable $q(x)=F(p(x))$ to get rid of $p$ and $p^2$ but I do not know how to proceed.

How would I simplify this equation in order to see if it reduces to a famous case?

Edit: Here is the full equation, in a more compact form where we can clearly see that $s=0$ reduces to the diffusion equation:
\begin{equation}
p_{xx}+s(p_x^2+p_{xx}-p_x(p-1+p_{xx}))+s^2(p_x^2-p(p+p_{xx})=(2+s)p_t
\end{equation}

Comment: When $s = 0$, this becomes $0 = 0$. Is there a typo in the formula?

Comment: I corrected the mistake and edited the question. Now is the correct version and we do recover $\frac{1}{2}p''(x)=0$ for $s=0$. But now the equation looks much more daunting...